# PHP: Find, store, address array key by index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have a very complex multi-dimensional array (**$tree**). I receive that large array as a reference.

Now, I need to find a certain key in it and insert data there.

Finding the needed key is easy. A function searches the array and returns the path **$path**. For instance, it returns the `$path = array('index1', 'index2', 'index3')`. Which means, that I would need to assign my data like `$tree['index1']['index2']['index3'] = $some_data_i_needed_to_insert`.

Now the problem appears is that I can't address that array index from the address I receive from the seatch function.

I tried like this:

```
<?php
$path = '[\'index1\'][\'index2\'][\'index3\']';
$tree{$path} = $some_data_i_needed_to_insert;
?>
```

Is there a way to address an array index in my case?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Could we see the first function? That might help clarify what the question is.

Comment: Why are you doing `$tree{'[1334][\'#below\'][3242]'}` ?

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no sane direct expression you can use to directly access a key if you have a path array. However, this'll do:

```
$path =  array('1334', '#below', '3242');
$node =& $complexArray;

foreach ($path as $key) {
    $node =& $node[$key];
}

$node = $data;
```